# Is there a generic English term for the relation actor:actress?

Tags: terminology, gender, onomastics

I am looking for a generic term describing the relation actor:actress or Paul:Paula, like *actress is a ____ of actor*. In German, there is the term *Movierung* for this, and it works in both directions (masculine -> feminine and feminine -> masculine), but looking up *Movierung* in dictionaries did not reveal an English equivalent.

P.S. Of course, I can say "a feminine form of" and "a masculine form of", including the direction of derivation. I am interested in a term on the same level of abstraction as *Movierung*.

Comment: Pairs of the type "actor - actress" are called gender-specific nouns, nouns of the type "actress" and "Paula" are called feminitives. _Movierung_ is close to "gender specification".

Comment: English uses terms like _Motionsfemininum_ as well, though obviously mostly in quite limited circles, and usually italicised as an obvious loan word. If your audience is linguists, there’s a good change they’ll understand _Movierung_ or _Motion_. For a general audience, though, I don’t think there’s a word for the concept, beyond descriptive phrases like ‘gendered derivation’ or somesuch.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: A high level "no" answer like yours is an acceptable outcome of this question to me.

Comment: There is nothing in the word *Movierung* to suggest it was specific to gender, unless that's short for *Mu-mu*, in which case it should mean femininum indeed. You could simply form a transparent *-ive* word, perhaps *genitive* if it wasn't already taken, or *sexis'* + *-ive*, quite express-ive really.